# Apache Nifi Deletehdfs issue

Tags: apache-nifi

I am getting the following issue. screenshot attached. Please help. thanks.
[image]

Comment: What version of NiFi?

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug that was corrected in the recently released version 1.2.0 of NiFi.

Information about this issue and the correction are available in the associated [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3204).